# Drawing on Canvas in AndEngine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

I want to access canvas in andengine to draw quads on it using QuadTo functions in Android.
Who would like to help me? If its not possible kindly provide me a solution for using quadto functions or drawing curved lines in andEngine

Comment: Check out this example: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/CanvasTextureCompositingExample.java which is similar to what you want to do.